# Select random element and set attribute background color

Tags: javascript, css, random

How do I give color red to random element with id "hello"?

```
<h1 id="hello">a</h1> <h1 id="hello">b</h1> <h1 id="hello">c</h1>
```

Comment: you can only have one element with id hello, maybe you should use class instead of id in this case

Comment: ok. If I do with class what should I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use class instead of id then you can do something like this.

- Get all the hello elements
- Create a random Index in the range from zero to the length of your elements
- Set the style.color of this random Index element in your helloElements to red

```js
let helloElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hello");


let ind = (Math.floor(Math.random() * helloElements.length))
console.log(ind);
helloElements[ind].style.color = "red";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="hello">a</h1> <h1 class="hello">b</h1> <h1 class="hello">c</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead of ID attribute and put hello there, like class="hello". I will show the example below using jquery

```js
var len = $(".hello").length;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len))
    $(".hello").eq(random).css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="hello">a</h1> <h1 class="hello">b</h1> <h1 class="hello">c</h1>
```